# Does Monodevelop support configuration files?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I added a file app.config to a C# mono project.

Inside the project I used

```
foreach (string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
{
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", key, value);
}
```

The config file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="Key1" value="Kevin" />
<add key="Key2" value="150" />
<add key="Key3" value="Rice" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

No keys are detected. How can I read the config values?

Comment: You should use ConfigurationManager to write the keys, and then read them back using ConfigurationManager.  If that succeeds, look for the XML file that it generated.

Comment: @robert - but I just need to read the config values from a file

Comment: If what I suggested succeeds, you will know where the XML file should be located, and how it should be properly formatted.  Once you know that, you can create the file manually.

Comment: @robert - Your suggestion works but no new file is added and no values are stored in the existing config file

Comment: There are three possibilities: 1) It created a file, but you didn't find it yet, 2) It didn't create a file, and you can't do what you want to do, 3) It is storing the information in a file that's already created somewhere else.

Comment: I got it, it was in the debug directory and I had to set the config file to overwrite it. 10x

Comment: @danip, might that be an asnwer then? :)

Answer (score 6):

This answer comes awfully late, but for anybody that comes across this, yes, mono does support configuration files.  You can use the ConfigurationManager method discussed above or you can even create your own custom settings section in the app.config file and manipulate it through a class which derives from ApplicationSettingsBase.  In my opinion, this is a much more natural way of handling the app.config file because you work with a class and strongly typed properties, rather than accessing strings out of an array with the way that ConfigurationManager does it.  Creating a class for app settings is pretty easy, too.  Here's the MSDN page explaining how to create the class:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx

The only caveat to be aware of with Mono is that the .NET Framework allows UserScopedSettings to be defined in the app.config file (to provide a default value) but Mono will throw exceptions if you do that.  The workaround for that is to leave UserScopedSettings out of the app.config file and just define the default value for a property in code.  This isn't a perfect workaround because it doesn't give a way to change the default value outside of the code, but this will be sufficient in most cases.